# How to use promises in NodeJS mongodb driver version 2.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I was reading [How to use MongoDB with promises in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911838/how-to-use-mongodb-with-promises-in-node-js) when I saw that in the first answer they say that if I pass no callback, mongo driver will return me a promise. It worked for 'connect' but it didn't work when I tried:

```
db.collection('myCollection').find().then((docs)=>{console.log(docs)})
```

I got:

```
MongoDB error: TypeError: db.collection(...).find(...).then is not a function
```

I tried to read the documentation for `find()` at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find and I can see some examples there that does things like this:

```
collection.find({}).explain().then(function(docs) {
      test.ok(docs != null);

      db.close();
    });
```

this is a Promise for find but it has this `explain()` thing. What is it? Also, why there is no mention of promises in this API? There's also another line that does:

```
collection.insertMany([{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}], {w:1}).then(function(result) {
```

which is also a promise.

So, how to use promises with find()?

Also, why this documentation won't tell the return values of anything? Neither the arguments I can use...

Comment: check this [tutorial](http://zshawnsyed.com/2015/05/04/mongo-db-promise/)!

Comment: That tutorial is for mongoose which is a different library.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `toArray()`, which works like you want (callback inside, or promise returned if not callback)

```
db.collection('...').find().toArray()
.then(function(docs) {
  // =)
});
```

This is because `db.collection('..').find()` returns a cursor, not a promise.

This behavior is intended because "find as a whole" is not the only pattern that can be used (ie. streams are allowed).