# Use Callbacks in NodeJs for implementing tranasactions with MongoDB 4.0?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, transactions

Is there any way of using transactions in MongoDB 4.0 with mongoose, without using `Promises`, I want to use `Callbacks` only?

I read this post [post](http://thecodebarbarian.com/a-node-js-perspective-on-mongodb-4-transactions.html) but didn't find anything with Callbacks.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you can do something along the lines:

`mongoose.startSession()
   .then(session => {//do some db operation})
   .then(//another one)
   .then(mongoose.endSession())
   .catch(session.abortTransaction());`

Please also refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911838/how-to-use-mongodb-with-promises-in-node-js?rq=1). It's not specific for MongoDB 4.0, but might help.

Comment: Thanks for telling me, But is it possible to do with only using `Callbacks`?

Comment: Yes @sudhanshu-gaur, you can pass a callback function as the last argument of `mongoose.startSession()`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-startSession

Answer (score -1):

Mongo DB not support Multi-Document Transactions:

> When a single write operation (e.g. db.collection.updateMany())
>   modifies multiple documents, the modification of each document is
>   atomic, but the operation as a whole is not atomic.

You can read more in the documentation:[MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#multi-document-transactions)

But there are some solutions for this, try to use this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-transactions

Comment: MongoDB 4.0 does support ACID transactions for multiple documents.